# DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH not inherited in shell

Tags: bash, macos

MacOS 12.7.2 I have a program that uses dlopen to load a dylib, it need DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH set to find it. But when I try to put the command in a shell script if fails because DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH is not inherited. Every other environment variable is.

```
~/felix-lang.github.io>cat xx.sh
echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
~/felix-lang.github.io>sh xx.sh

~/felix-lang.github.io>echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
/Users/skaller/felix/build/release/host/lib/rtl
```

The dlopen uses a simple relative name so searching in the path is essential. Any clues what is going on?

This is a workaround:

```
export XX=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
~/felix-lang.github.io>cat xx.sh
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$XX
echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

That actually works, i.e. my program runs fine. But I shouldn't need to do this.

---- EDIT ----
Here is more data and tests thanks to @Charles Duffy.

```
~/felix-lang.github.io>declare -p DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
declare -x DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Users/skaller/felix/build/release/host/lib/rtl"
```

However

```
~/felix-lang.github.io>printenv | grep LIBRARY
CAML_LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/skaller/.opam/5.1.1/lib/stublibs:/Users/skaller/.opam/5.1.1/lib/ocaml/stublibs:/Users/skaller/.opam/5.1.1/lib/ocaml
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/skaller/felix/build/release/host/lib/rtl
```

`printenv` doesn't show it. It can be exported in the current terminal and is STILL not inherited in a subshell.

```
~/felix-lang.github.io>export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="HelloWorld"
~/felix-lang.github.io>sh
~/felix-lang.github.io>echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH

~/felix-lang.github.io>
```

Finally here is a quote from a man page that explains things and says explicitly DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH is an environment variable.

> In general, dyld does not search for dylibs.  Dylibs are specified via a
> full path, either as a static dependent dylib in a mach-o file, or as a
> path passed to dlopen() , But during development the env vars
> DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH and DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH can be used to override the
> specified path and look for the leaf framework/dylib name in the specified
> directories.

In most development you link against an installed library so the variable is not required. The lack of searching is a security measure to prevent hijacking. For `dlopen` you should give the full path. But my policy is to give only the basename of the path and let the system search because the program doesn't, in fact, know where plugins live, and indeed you might want to replace one (that is, allow hijacking). This is just to explain how the issue arises: I didn't want to write my own search procedure just to find an absolute pathname for `dlopen`.

Comment: You absolutely _should_ need to export variables for child processes to see them. Unexported shell variables are local to the shell and don't survive a `fork()`; environment space is a limited resource (there's a shared limit for the size of the per-process block of memory used for environment variables and command-line options); you don't want a world where all shell variables are also environment variables, because (1) there'd be a much lower limit on how many you can have and their size, and (2) as you used that space your max command line length would get shorter.

Comment: BTW, you can just `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` or (in bash) `declare -x DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` to copy the existing shell variable into an environment variable (and keep them in sync thereafter); no need to pass the value on the export command line.

Comment: Your workaround works because `XX` was exported, not because you used it as a level of indirection to assign to `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Your original `xx.sh` would work just as well if you executed `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` before executing `xx.sh`.

Comment: Mind, there _are_ cases where DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH (and some other variables that are similarly sensitive to being used for arbitrary code execution attacks) specifically are cleared from the environment, but those are cases where there's a privileges boundary being crossed (f/e, if you're running a setuid/setgid executable); if that's where you're at, you haven't entered it into evidence in the question.

Comment: BTW, if you want to prove to us that your DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH _is_ already exported, a reasonable way to do that (assuming your parent shell is bash per your tags and not sh per your usage -- they're not the same thing; even when provided by the same executable, bash runs in a feature-limited compatibility mode when started under the `sh` name) is `declare -p DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`. If it says `declare -- DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH='...'` that means it's a regular shell variable; if it says `declare -x DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH='...'` that means it's an environment variable.

Comment: DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH is indeed exported in $HOME/.bash_profile as is PATH etc. And your suggested test 'proves' it. ``~/felix-lang.github.io>declare -p DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
declare -x DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Users/skaller/felix/build/release/host/lib/rtl"```

Comment: So whoever closed this topic should reopen it.

Comment: ~/felix-lang.github.io>declare -p DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
declare -x DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Users/skaller/felix/build/release/host/lib/rtl"

Comment: It seems this particular environment variable is being deliberately clobbered. And I would guess APPLE is doing this because it is an APPLE specific variable used to control dynamic loading. The variable is used to OVERRIDE hard coded paths and so setting it can "magically" change the behaviour of programs.

Comment: As a matter of interest `printenv` does NOT list it. In any case it seems an Apple expert need to answer my question. I have a whole host of programs that rely on run time loading of plugins. Unfortunately I also have a way of statically "preloading" them so I have not noticed this issue before.

Comment: declare -x DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH does not work.

Comment: I also tried a subshell using bash and zsh. Same problem. Also when spawning a Makefle. I haven't checked (have to write low level C to do so) but my *guess* is that when a child process is created by Mach there is a routine which copies the environment of the parent to the child and sets the current process ID etc. In fact I have a variable called `SHLVL` which counts the nesting depth of shells. So I guess this routine is *removing* DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: So IMO at this time this is not a shell issue, but a Mach OS kernel issue. I believe it's not a bug but a deliberate security tightening but I'd really like to hear from a MacOS expert. If I have to change my deployment model it will be a non-trivial change to my system.